# Weird smartctl output. Is my disk in danger?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware, smart

I have a disk, that gets me kinda weird smartctl output. I have never seen such large nubmbers on other disks.

Does anyone now how to interpret these ? Is the disk likely to be faulty ?

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   118   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       188529080
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   093   093   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       10
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   076   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       43660824
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   067   067   000    Old_age   Always       -       29739
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       10
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4295032833
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   066   059   045    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 24/35)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       7519
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   034   041   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (0 19 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       133358734570326
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       137919765438422
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       78309414368650

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

The hard disk is a ST3000DM001 running on a Debain GNU/Linux box with Kernel 3.16.0 and smartmontools 5.41

best regards

K.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this useful table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes), the only critical value in your case would be

```
188 Command_Timeout  0x0032  100  100  000  Old_age  Always  -  4295032833
```

> The count of aborted operations due to HDD timeout. Normally this attribute value should be equal to zero and if the value is far above zero, then most likely there will be some serious problems with power supply or an oxidized data cable.

I would also check if your file system detected anything out of the ordinary and do a full scrubbing of all disks if possible (assuming you use file systems with integrity checking, like ZFS or btrfs) to catch any hidden problems. SMART attributes are useful to see when you should start ordering replacement disks, but it can't answer the reverse question "Is everything alright currently?" - except for a "Probably yes, but who knows...".